# Calculus - $ \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\alpha )\sum_{k=1}^n {k^\alpha \over n^{1+\alpha}} = 1 $ ( Homework assignment )

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

First of all I want to mention that this is about an assignement I was given at school. I don't need the straight answer as much as a few hints to get started.

To give you a context, at the moment we're studying series and how they behave when n goes to infinity.

This is where I'm at :

Let $\alpha > 0$ ,  $ S_n(\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha$ and $T_n(\alpha) = {n^{1+\alpha}\over 1+\alpha}$. Proove :

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} {S_n(\alpha) \over T_n(\alpha)} = 1  $$

I managed to get to :

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} {S_n(\alpha) \over T_n(\alpha)} = (1+\alpha).\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left({1 \over n}\right).\sum_{k=1}^n\left({k \over n}\right)^\alpha\right) $$

I really want to use this :

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left({1 \over n}\right).\sum_{k=1}^n\left({k \over n}\right)^\alpha\right) = \int_0^1 x^\alpha.dx $$

Which is something you can figure out with rectangle areas under the graph of $x^\alpha$ and it would allow me to get the correct answer. Is there a theorem I'm missing somewhere ? What would be the proof of this last equation ?

Thanks to anyone that might help =)

Comment: The last displayed line is just from the definition of the Riemann integral. The expression inside the limit is a Riemann sum for the partition of $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals of length $\frac{1}n$.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I knew I was missing something, Riemann Integral it is =) I've been out of school for 8 years and I'm starting back since mid-september, I don't remember everything and this is making everything more complex, thanks again for your help =)

Comment: My pleasure! Rusty or not, you were definitely thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Set $x_k=\dfrac kn$, and rewrite your sum as
$$(1+\alpha )\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^\alpha.$$

Comment: Thanks bernard, I tried to do as you said but I can't really find any use for it. I went the route of trying to identify a geometric suit but to no avail. It appears it's a case of a Riemann integral which by itself prove the last equation I wrote. I would be interested to know if there is a demonstration of it ( the only things I could find is that the Riemann integral is the historical definition of an integral ).

Comment: Leaving aside the 1 + α factor, your expression is a *Riemann sum* of the function $x^\alpha$ (the upper Riemann sum, more precisely). Hence the limit, by definition, is the  integral of this  function between the bounds that are left to you.